# Nets and sequences in countable sets.

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, nets

Assume $A$ is topological space and $A$ is countable, the for any net $\left\{ x_{\alpha}\right\} \subset A$, can we conclude that $\left\{ x_{\alpha}\right\}$  is actually a sequence in $A$?

Comment: Do you know the _definitions_  of "net" and "sequence"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a sequence is a net with **index set** $\Bbb N$ in its standard order, the space in which we work is irrelevant. A net can assume two values and not be a sequence, etc.

That is why sequences can have subnets that are not (sub)sequences, e.g.

Comment: At least, over countable spaces can we say "sequences are enough to characterize all topological properties"?

Answer (score 1):

A extreme example is the space $\beta\mathbb N$, the [Stone-Cech compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93%C4%8Cech_compactification) of the discrete space $\mathbb N$.

The sequence $x_n = n$ in that space has no convergent subsquence; but (since $\beta\mathbb N$ is compact) it does have a convergent subnet.

So, to answer your question: Yes, there are nets in $\mathbb N$ that are not sequences.

Answer (score 0):

No.

A "sequence" is a function from $\mathbb{N}$ to a topological space $X.$

A "net" is a function from a directed set $\theta$ to a topological space $X.$

So you can see that any sequence is a net. but there are nets which are not sequences.

for ex: consider $f:[0,1] \to [0,1]$ where $f(x)=x$ is a net. but it is not a sequence.